# Restricting one view on Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin, flask-security, flask-principal

I have a single file for a Flask application, `views.py`.

Inside `views.py`, I have the setup for `Flask-Admin` and the corresponding `sqlalchemy` database here:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(flaskapp)

def build_db():

import random
import datetime

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

# Create sample Users
testuser = []
testgroup = []
testlevel = []

user_list = []
for i in range(len(testuser)):
    user = User()
    user.testuser = testuser[i]
    user.testlevel = testlevel[i]
    user.testgroup = testgroup[i]

    user_list.append(user)
    db.session.add(user)

for user in user_list:
    entry = random.choice(sample_text)  # select text at random
    post = Post()
    post.user = user
    post.title = entry['title']
    post.text = entry['content']
    tmp = int(1000*random.random())  # random number between 0 and 1000:
    post.date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=tmp)
    post.tags = random.sample(tag_list, 2)  # select a couple of tags at random
    db.session.add(post)

db.session.commit()
return

# Create models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    testuser = db.Column(db.String(100))
    testgroup = db.Column(db.String(100))
    testlevel = db.Column(db.String(100))

# Required for administrative interface. For python 3 please use __str__ instead.
def __repr__(self):
    return self.testuser

class UserInfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    key = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String(64))

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='info')

def __repr__(self):
    return '%s - %s' % (self.key, self.value)

### Attempt at doing something...
class MyView(ModelView):
    @expose('/admin/userview', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def adminview():
        return "yes"
##ADMIN
admin = Admin(flaskapp, name="Test Aptly")
admin.add_view(MyView(User, db.session))
```

The Question.

How do I block access to the "/admin/userview" page depending on what level the user is (defined with the database "testlevel")? Users have 3 qualities, An example for two users would be:

```
testuser          testgroup        testlevel

joe               it               admin

john              dev              basic
```

How would I restrict the admin page to only let people with `testlevel="admin"`?
Do I use Flask-Security? Flask-Principal? If so, how? I've been tinkering with both for a little bit and I haven't gotten anything working so far.

Here's an example "/admin/userview" looks like: [example Flask-Admin](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.6/db_sqla/)

> First of all, you can use various class-level properties to configure
>   what should be displayed and how. For example, column_list can be used
>   to show some of the column or include extra columns from related
>   models.
>
> **For example**:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    # Show only name and email columns in list view
    column_list = ('name', 'email')

    # Enable search functionality - it will search for terms in
    # name and email fields
    column_searchable_list = ('name', 'email')

    # Add filters for name and email columns
    column_filters = ('name', 'email')
```

> Alternatively, you can override some of the ModelView methods and
>   implement your custom logic.
>
> For example, if you need to contribute additional field to the
>   generated form, you can do something like this:

```
class UserView(ModelView):
    def scaffold_form(self):
        form_class = super(UserView, self).scaffold_form()
        form_class.extra = wtf.TextField('Extra')
        return form_class
```

> Check [flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqlamodel documentation](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/v1.0.6/api/mod_contrib_sqlamodel/) for list of
>   configuration properties and methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume that you subclassed `BaseView` to create your admin view and that you are using Flask-login.

Then override the `is_accessible` method in your view class, to check the current user's quality:

```
from flask.ext.admin.base import BaseView
from flask.ext.login import current_user

class MyView(BaseView):
    def is_accessible(self):
        return current_user.testlevel == 'admin'
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I should have also put that I use kerberos to get the username like so:

`request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')`

I haven't subclassed anything, what I posted there is everything I used to get Flask-Admin/sqlalchemy up and running. I have no idea where Flask-Admin keeps its web pages or anything :/

Comment: If `request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')` contains the username (as a string) you can query your database to get his testlevel.

Regarding subclassing, there must be some place where you create an `Admin` object and add views to it (example [here](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#adding-views)). Which class are you using in `admin.add_view(...)`?

Comment: Yea I've been doing it throughout the Flask app, but with Flask-Admin I haven't been able to get it to work with querying the database.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you have to initialize Flask-Admin? Will help figuring out why you're not able to run queries specifically with Flask-Admin.

Comment: Won't let me edit but at the bottom of the code above is how I initialize Flask-Admin

`admin = Admin(flaskapp, name="Test Aptly")`
`admin.add_view(MyView(User, db.session))`

Comment: Browse your code to find where the `MyView` class is declared. As you instantiate it with a `session` I guess it is subclassed from `ModelView`. Within such a view you can access the database session with `self.session`, from here you can query for the appropriate `User` (`self.session.query(User).filter(...)`) and check whether it has the right `testlevel`.